# Reading a json file from Heroku Project Directory

Tags: java, heroku

Hi am new to heroku java development. Well I want to read a config.json file from the project directory, but somehow am unable to figure out where the file needs to be kept. Tried keeping the same in src>main>resources but am still getting filenotfound after deployment. Any idea how to refer the file? . My file is located at src/main/resources/config.json.

Tried doing something like this 
`FileInputStream stream  =new FileInputStream( LoadConfig.class.getResource("Config.json").getPath());`

Main issue is am not sure where to keep the config.json file.

Answer (score 4):

The general idea of what you are doing should work and `src/main/resources` is the right place to keep  files like that with a Maven project, as they will get copied to `target/classes` during the Maven build to be available on the classpath, but a couple pointers:

- Make sure you have the capitalization of the file correct. You mentioned that the file is `config.json`, but your code is using `Config.json`.
- You are loading the file relative to the `LoadConfig.class` which would be in its package directory. For example, if the fully qualified name is `com.example.LoadConfig.class`, you would be looking for `Config.json` in the `target/classes/com/example` directory, not the base `target/classes`. To make things simpler, you might want to just use the system classloader to load the file so you don't have to think about relative paths, like this:

  ```
  FileInputStream stream = new FileInputStream(ClassLoader.getSystemResource("Config.json").getPath());
  ```
- The build and runtime on Heroku should be the same as running on your own machine with Maven 3 and OpenJDK 6/7/8. Make sure you are able to get this working locally before deploying to Heroku.